# Выравнивание блоков относительно border

Tags: html, css, текст

Подскажите плиз, как добиться такого эффекта? Чтобы линия(border) начиналась с конца второй строки?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

По мотивам скриншота...

```css
.punkt {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 45px sans-serif;
}
.punkt::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .25em; margin-left: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em; width: 100%;
  border-bottom: .1em dashed currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="punkt">Номер полиса выдан заведомо ложный</div>
```